# How do I set my friend feed to include user statuses?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a social networking site and I have two types of statuses. Friends and Public. Users can upload to either. The relevant tables for this question are members, friends, and status. Relevant field for members is Handle. Relevant fields for friends are Friend and Username. Relevant fields for status is Handle and type(with values friends or public).

I managed to call the statuses I needed for only friends, but my question is how do I get it to show friends as well as the user's statuses

Here's the code that shows all statuses from a user's friends.

```
$shawing = "SELECT *
FROM status
JOIN friends
ON status.Handle = friends.Friend where friends.Username='$members[Handle]' and status.Type='friends' ORDER by status.Id DESC" or print mysql_error();

$members[Handle] calls from an include that identifies the user who is logged in.
```

I know it's probably simple but how do I correct it to show both the friends AND user statuses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION them together (merge two queries)

```
$shawing = "
    SELECT 1 IsUser, '$members[Handle]' Friend, status.*
    FROM status
    where status.Handle='$members[Handle]'
      and status.Type='friends'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 IsUser, friends.Friend, status.*
    FROM status
    JOIN friends ON status.Handle = friends.Friend
    where friends.Username='$members[Handle]'
      and status.Type='friends'
    ORDER by IsUser, status.Id DESC" or print mysql_error();
```

Comment: Okay, well I tried adding that, and now I get an error with my while.

Comment: $shawing = "
    SELECT '$members[Handle]' Friend, status.*
    FROM status
    where status.Handle='$members[Handle]'
      and status.Type='friends'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT friends.Friend, status.*
    FROM status
    JOIN friends ON status.Handle = friends.Friend
    where friends.Username='$members[Handle]'
      and status.Type='friends'
      ORDER by status.Id DESC" or print mysql_error();


$booga=mysql_query($shawing);



while($row=mysql_fetch_array($booga))
{

Comment: Also the while works fine with the code I provided in my original post.

Comment: for reference the error is Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/reaper/public_html/friendzzone.php on line 35

Which occurs on the start of my while.

Comment: @Brad try changing the last part to just `ORDER by Id DESC`

Comment: That got rid of the error, thank you, but it still just shows friend statuses.

Comment: What do you get for running just the TOP part? i.e. before UNION ALL `SELECT '$members[Handle]' Friend, status.*
    FROM status
    where status.Handle='$members[Handle]'
      and status.Type='friends'`

Comment: If I just run `$shawing = "SELECT '$members[Handle]' Friend, status.* FROM status where status.Handle='$members[Handle]' and status.Type='friends'"
$booga=mysql_query($shawing);` I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/reaper/public_html/friendzzone.php on line 67

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the ; let me try it again.

Comment: Okay, if I run it with just the first part, it works. It shows the statuses from the user. I don't understand why it wouldn't show both? Is it because of my while?

Comment: @Brad - run the UNION ALL query again, and you should see the user in there somewhere, sorted randomly among the rest. Actually, look at the edited answer - user's own status is listed first

Comment: The code you gave me shows only the most recent post. Just one.

Comment: Also I just logged in under another test account and made a status update to the friends zone. I can confirm it does call from either the user or the friend but now it shows only 1

Answer (score 0):

Change it to a 'right join'. You're blocking on values for 'status' that don't have related entries in 'friends'. You could probably lose lots of the 'where' clause too.

Comment: Thanks. But what do you mean by dropping the where clause? I need it to select only from statuses in the friends section. Theres public statuses, and friends statuses. What would the RIGHT JOIN code look like? I tried but now its giving me errors.

Comment: Okay, I managed to get the code to work with RIGHT JOIN but it still only shows friend statuses.